# Error in Database connection code, Xcode 4 & Sqlite3

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, sqlite

I keep getting an error that says "Called type NSString is not a function or a function pointer. I've been stuck for days trying things. Any I dea where my problem is?

```
- (void)saveData
{

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &testdb1) == SQLITE_OK)
    {


        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO TESTDB1"
                               (email, username, password, age) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                                email.text, username.text, password.text, age.integer];


        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(testdb1, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
           status.text = @"User added";
           email.text = @"";
           username.text = @"";
           password.text = @"";
           age.text = @"";
        } else {
           status.text = @"Failed to add user";
        }
          sqlite3_finalize(statement);
          sqlite3_close(testdb1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO TESTDB1"
                   (email, username, password, age)
```

You're closing the quotation marks too early; if you look closely to the expression, you can notice

```
@"INSERT INTO TESTDB" (email, username, password, age)
```

So the compiler sees you're trying to call an NSString as a function. Change your format string literal to

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO TESTDB1 (email, username, password, age) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                    email.text, username.text, password.text, age.integer];
```

and you should be fine to go.

P. s.: **do have a look at the preview** before posting your question - it's terribly formatted as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a quote at the beginning of the second line of your stringWithFormat call.